# Required input CSS selector equivalent in Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, css, angular-reactive-forms

Is there an equivalent way of `input:required {CSS}` to select with CSS all the reactive form fields in Angular that have `Validators.required` in its formControl? Or there is some workaround to do this?

Comment: can try this `.ng-valid[required], .ng-valid.required { CSS }`

Comment: This is not working...

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2 (working)**

Angular doesn't provide a solution to get the validators of a FormControl, which means we would have to revert to rather hacky solutions

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13461
- https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2574

What they basically do currently is loop through the FormControls, execute the validators on an empty control

```
const validator = abstractControl.validator({}as AbstractControl);
            if (validator && validator.required) {
                return true;
            }
```

and check if it has required validator on it.
while this does technically work, it executes all synchronous validators!
you can then for example get a reference to the nativeElements of the form controls and compare them by `formControlName`.

I created a stackblitz to illustrate it
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hifypw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

the required FormControl will rendered with a red background.
I used a template Variable `theForm` to get a hold of the Element which holds the `FormGroup` and then select every child of type `input`.
I then loop over them and check if they have the required validator.
To compare I use the formControlName

```
 const controls =  this.getValidators(this.frmMain.controls);
      this.elements.forEach(x => {
            x.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(i => {

              const c = controls[i.attributes['formcontrolname'].value];

              if(i.attributes['formcontrolname'] && c && c.required && !i.classList.contains('test')) {
                i.classList.add('test');
              }

            });
    })
```

I think it's a lot of work, for something rather simple.
Also my approach would currently only work if all form controls are within the same component (and it of course only includes input) and I have no idea if it would work with AOT.

It works, but I'd rather use a a custom directive or just a plain and simple css class.

**UPDATE**

currently the only solution, I come up is creating a class `.required` and add it manually.

Maybe you could somehow use a combination of `@ViewChildren` and `FormControl` to get what you want. I will investigate, but it will probably a bit hacky.

**BELOW ONLY WORKS FOR TEMPLATE DRIVEN FORMS**

you could use `input[type=text][required]` and so forth.

While this would basically work, I think it's a very broad selector which will probably lead to problems latter in your project and you will be writing some ugly css rules just to circumvent this rule.
What I would do is create a css class to denote a form-control, like bootstrap framework does it.

Something like `.form-control[required]`.
Keep in mind that styling radio buttons and checkboxes works quite differently than text fields and select boxes.
For example you can't set borders on `<input type="checkbox" />` and `<input type="radio" />`

So you might even be more specific (and still not be too specific)
 `.form-control[type="text"][required]`

or another solution, just create a css class `.required` and be decoupled from angular.

Comment: Sorry but this solution does not work because it seems that Reactive forms does not inject any [required] attribute to the HTML element referred...

Comment: well, stupid me, I had our Reactive Forms App in front of me and managed to pick the one control which was not a standard input and actually had the attribute, sorry about that. I'll edit my post

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution for reactive forms, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Arikael, I think this is the best workaround right now but unfortunately it is not the solution to the problem so as a result the best "solution" is to add a simple CSS class manually.

Comment: if my answer helped, could you accept it as an answer :)